Recovering indices from an expression
I have a long list and one element in that list is:

U[1, 3] U[1, 4] U[1, 5] U[2, 2] U[3, 1]

All entries of the list have the same structure of products of U[i,j]'s.  In the current instance this is a product of 5 terms but it could be a product of n terms.
Is there a way to extract from the "monomial"  U[1, 3]U[1, 4]U[1, 5]U[2, 2]U[3, 1] the first entries (1,1,1,2,3) and the second entries (3,4,5,2,1) of each factor of the monomial?

Oh dear... I was working too hard.  This will do it.
vars = Variables[U[1, 3] U[1, 4] U[1, 5] U[2, 2] U[3, 1]];
firstindex = Table[vars[[q]][[1]], {q, 1,Length[vars]}];
secondindex = Table[vars[[q]][[2]], {q, 1, Length[vars]}]


firstindex = vars[[All, 1]] is even simpler.

@SjoerdSmit yeah even simpler.  Thanks.

For
expr = U[1, 3] U[1, 4] U[1, 5] U[2, 2] U[3, 1];

you can do
{firstindex, secondindex} = Transpose[List @@@ List @@ expr]

or
{firstindex, secondindex} = expr /. {Times -> List, U -> List} // Transpose


Given,
expression = U[1, 3]  U[1, 4]  U[1, 5]  U[2, 2]  U[3, 1]

you could use Cases:
Cases[expression, U[a_, b_] :> {a, b}]
(* {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}} *)

or
Cases[expression, mono_U :> List @@ mono]
(* {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}} *)

That gives you both idices simultaneously, but it should be obvious how to adapt that to just one or the other if that's really what you want.

thanks.  I can see how this would be very useful.
